# Can you add 's' to a word after using "Does"

Tags: verbs, do-support

I don't know what it's called, but can you ask like "Does it hurts" or - "Does he loves her"?

From what I know you can't add s to a word after using "does" I don't know how adding the s is called, please let me know if you can.

I want to make sure you can't do that, and it has to be "hurt" and "love"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that.  When you use a modal or a helping verb, like **to do**, the main verb stays in *bare infinitive* form, which is the base form of the verb without *to*; you do not *conjugate* the main verb, which means to make it match the subject.

"He *eats*", but "**Does** he **eat**?" not "Does he *eats*?""
"She *helps*", but "Can she **help**?" not "Can she *helps*?"
etc.